# Finding smaller/sleek/exact font for ubuntu lts 20.04 in terminal mode

Tags: command-line, 20.04, fonts, display-resolution

I need help to adjust my terminal command-line-mode font to smaller and more clear/accurate font. I have ubuntu lts 20.04 installed on Lenovo Ideapad Y450. The screen resolution is 1366*768 14 inch screen. More detailed specs below. I have tried

```
dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

and trial/error different font selection and severely screwed up/garbled the screen fonts in terminal mode. Kindly help if you know how to apply font change, verify without having to reboot.

specs :
[https://www.amazon.com/Lenovo-Ideapad-Y450-14-Inch-Laptop/dp/B002DW95RW/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002DW95RW)

neofetch output below:

[image]

Current Terminal mode font [ which is a big too big ]:

[image]

The current console-setup file is like below :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem accidentally.

- This laptop has Nvidia graphics card. Hence I was using Nvidia driver for the ubuntu lts 20.04. This was chosen during the installation as an option  [third-party drivers]. I upgraded from 5.4 to 5.8 kernel on ubuntu 20.04 LTS [ 2 days ago ]. I was not able to login into UI mode after install since this driver was causing issues. so i uninstalled it and rebooted. surprise!! I was able to login into UI mode using default driver and also command line / terminal mode is much more clear/small/accurate font. I had to use xrandr tool and a small script to set my required resolution at startup or UI login. works like a charm now!!

**steps to resolve :**

1. First of all list all the graphics drivers as shown in the below.I had the nvidia 340 driver installed [ which is indicated as recommended ].The reason I thought was Nvidia is always fussy in Linux so my thought was that it is better to use vendor provided graphics driver than the default one.
   [image]
2. Remove the driver using the below command.

   apt remove -y nvidia-340.
3. Now from the specification of the laptop and manual we know that the optimal and best resolution possible is 1368 X 768. When I removed the video driver and restarted the laptop, I got a much worse resolution which means larger icons in graphic mode. At this point, I also checked the terminal or text mode and the text resolution was the optimal and vert small but clear and sleek font. This was one problem solved.
4. I came back to UI login mode and logged in. Next was fixing resolution. To do this I created a script that would be autorun after I login into my account. This script looks like below.

[image]

5. I added this script to startup scripts or programs like the below.
   [image]

6. I logged out and logged back in again. To verify that my resolution is good now every time I log in. It works and there is no side effect or other problems due to this.

Lesson learned: avoid Nvidia graphics card package installation on Lenovo IdeaPad Y450 and resort to default driver instead.

Comment: You should include the "small script" to be a helpful answer to others. Also explain the "small script" and how it works. Also if this is a bad driver issue then the driver version should be stated in the question. The good driver version should be stated in the answer.

Comment: I have given detailed steps as you requested above. Kindly review and help if you see something not clear here.

Comment: It all looks good except you should use copy and paste from terminal screen into your posts. Doing a screen shot of a terminal makes it harder to read and impossible for other people to copy text into their own terminal to test.